# scandir() display file found/not found error messge

Tags: php, file, glob, scandir

I have 100 files and I am scanning them and picking the correct file out of them.

I am using the following code:

```
 $dir    = 'myDir';
 $files1 = scandir($dir);

 $scanned_directory = array_diff($files1, array('..', '.'));


 foreach ($scanned_directory as $key => $value) {
    $onlyname=explode(".", $value);
    if($onlyname[0]== $name){
        // echo "file found";
        break;
    }else{
        //echo "<h2>Not Found. Please Try Later</h2>";
    }

 }
```

The problem with this is that if the file is the 10th file I get 9x **not found**, before I get the file found message.

What is the proper way to display error message if no file is found?

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: used the in_array to detect the file in the scanned dir..i read about the glob which is somewhat of a specialized scandir()..but i haven't used it so far will do it in the future..your answer is the way to go..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit.

First of all I get all files from your directory into an array with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Then I simply grab all files which have the name `$name` with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and check with [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) if there is at least 1 file with that specific name.

```
<?php

    $dir = "myDir";
    $files = glob($dir . "/*.*");

    if(count(preg_grep("/^$name\..*$/", array_map("basename", $files))) > 0)
        echo "file found";
    else
        echo "<h2>Not Found. Please Try Later</h2>";

?>
```